# Count records in same column with and without parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having some trouble with a query and was hoping someone could help.  I have tried searching for a solution, but can't seem to find a similar scenario with my search terms.

Here is what I am looking for:

I have a table with three columns and need to return the values in the first column, and two counts of the values in the second column.  One count is based on a parameter and the other is the total count.  Ideally, I would only like to return the values in column one that have equal counts.

For example:

```
Part Number | Make ID
ABC123      | 1<br>
ABC123      | 1<br>
ABC123      | 3<br>
DEF456      | 1<br>
DEF456      | 1

Part Number | Count of Apps Where Make ID = 1| Count of Total Apps
ABC123      |                              2 | 3
DEF456      |                              2 | 2
```

The query I have so far will return the total count of apps for part numbers that have the parameter value, but I need it to return both counts:

```
SELECT apps.part#, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT application#)apps 
FROM   [mytable] AS apps 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT part# 
                   FROM   [mytable] 
                   WHERE  make = '1') AS sz 
               ON sz.part# = apps.part# 
GROUP  BY apps.part# 
ORDER  BY 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, everyone!  I received several correct answers, and selected the one that was give first:

```
SELECT part#, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN application# END) make1_apps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT application#) total_apps
FROM   [mytable]
GROUP  BY part#
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN application# END)
     = COUNT(DISTINCT application#)
ORDER  BY part#
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT part#, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN application# END) make1_apps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT application#) total_apps
FROM   [mytable]
GROUP  BY part#
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN application# END)
     = COUNT(DISTINCT application#)
ORDER  BY part#;
```

The HAVING clause ensures the two counts match.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    apps.part#
,   COUNT(*)
,   SUM(CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [mytable]
GROUP BY apps.part#
```

This solution replaces counting with calculating a sum, and supplying `1` for matching items and `0` for non-matching ones.

To filter out the records where the two counts are different, add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    apps.part#
,   COUNT(*)
,   SUM(CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [mytable]
GROUP BY apps.part#
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN make = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: This returns the correct counts.  Same question as above...Now, is there a way to return only the records where the count of the records with the make id parameter equals the count of the total apps and is greater than 0?

Comment: @user955289 Sure - take a look at the edit. You do not need an explicit check for zero, because `GROUP BY` cannot produce rows with the count of `0`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [Part Number],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Make ID] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY [Part Number]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2c728/1)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT [Part Number],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Make ID] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY [Part Number]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Make ID] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2c728/3)

Comment: This returns the correct counts.  Now, is there a way to return only the records where the count of the records with the make id parameter equals the count of the total apps and is greater than 0?

Answer (score 2):

another way more similar to yours:

```
select d.[Part Number], count(d.[Part Number]), o.ones
from
  data d
cross apply
(
  select count(*)
  from data d2
  where d2.[Part Number] = d.[Part Number]
      and d2.[Make ID] = 1
) o (ones)
group by d.[Part Number],  o.ones
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f40a/6)

to fullfill your second request add:

```
having count(d.[Part Number]) = o.ones
```